Multi-tenancy with custom domains and react/remix
I have set up a backend API that handles multitenancy using multiple databases which connects based on the custom domain that is browed to.
I'm certain there is a better way, and as this was my very first react project, I chose remix w/vite as it seemed like a good place to start to handle routing and some minor things.  I attempted to go stateless outside of those state features provided by react and remix.
So on to my question/problem.  I have components setup that call a Service, which in turn calls a get/post/put function configured using fetch.  Because of vite/remix, I can't immediately pull the hostname to figure out which url to call for the API.  I know now that remix is supposed to be SSR and some say to use Prisma to handle database calls.  If I understood more at the time, I may have done so, but like I said, this was my first foray into react, but not web in general (came from vue).
Short version: My react/remix components call a service, which calls an EP, without passing in the hostname to the service/function (since these are SSR?), is there a nicer way to configure the URL required for the API call?  Should I just add a state/loader or some other method?
Any advice is appreciated, I would rather not start from scratch again at this point, but what I may do is remove Remix to get this particular project finished and try the next one with full remix w/SSR and db access.
Thank you.
